# How to programmatically parse/retrieve user's parameters in Intellij project from Gradle build file

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I need to retrieve some user specific parameters from Gradle build file in an Intellij project (build.gradle.kts)
Here a "build.gradle.kts" file content example I need to parse:

```
cutomParameters {
   param1.set("any value")
   sub_parameters1 {
      sub_parameter1_1.set("foo")
   }
   subParameters2 {
      subParameter21("foo")
      subParameter22 {
         subParameter221.set("foo")
      }
   }
}
```

I tried some code like this:

```kotlin
val connection: ProjectConnection =
GradleConnector.newConnector().forProjectDirectory(File(projectPath)).connect()

val model = connection.model(GradleBuild::class.java)
```

I can get the gradle build file using `model.get().buildFile` but how to retrieve the custom parameters described in the previous example?

Comment: Is the `cutomParameters` a typo?

Comment: It's an example (custom parameters are directly set at build.gradle.kts root). I think this is not a good practice, I've seen "ext" block should be used but this "ext" block seems not allowing a hierachical parameters structure.